# Convexity and positivity of the second fundamental form

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature, geodesic

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth bounded open set in a complete Riemannian manifold $(M^n,g)$, $n\geq 2$, and denote by $N$ the outward unit normal for $\partial \Omega$.

Is it true that $\Omega$ is (strictly) convex if and only if the second fundamental form of its boundary with respect to $N$ is nonnegative (positive definite)? If so, do you have a reference for these facts?

Just to recall, we say that $\Omega$ is convex if for any $x,y \in \Omega$ the minimizing geodesic in $M$ that joins these points lies entirely in $\Omega$. It is strictly convex if for any $x,y \in \overline{\Omega}$ the interior of the minimizing geodesic in M joining these points lies in $\Omega$.

Finally, the second fundamental form of $\partial \Omega$ with respect to $N$ at a point $x \in \partial \Omega$ is the symmetric bilinear form $B : T_x \partial \Omega \times T_x \partial \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$ B(v,w) = g( \nabla_v N, w).$$

Comment: Did you think of examples of graphs of convex functions of one variable? Does failure of the 2nd derivative test imply that a function is not **strictly** convex?

Comment: Ok, so the epigraph of $x^4$ is strictly convex although the second fundamental form of the boundary vanishes at the origin. However, the epigraph is convex and the second fundamental form of the boundary is nonnegative. Is this true in general?

Comment: This is fine...